# 2-layered model works, but 3-layered model trained iwth same data has NaN values

Tags: tensorflow, keras

The follwoing code goes through without problems

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.mae,
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(),
              metrics=["mae"])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=100)
```

The call to `fit()` gives normal output:

```
Epoch 1/100
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 2ms/step - loss: 8602.7510 - mae: 8602.7510
Epoch 2/100
34/34 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 7890.7075 - mae: 7890.7075
Epoch 3/100
  ...
```

`X_train` and `y_train` are tensors with shapes (1070,11) and (1070,)
However, when i add a third layer to the model

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])
```

and leave the rest of the code untouched, i get `nan` losses:

```
Epoch 1/100
34/34 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: nan - mae: nan
Epoch 2/100
34/34 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: nan - mae: nan
Epoch 3/100
 ---
```

I tried different values for the layer sizes, but the result is unchanged.
I assume the training data is "clean", because it caused no error with the simple model.

I suspect that there might be a shape problem causing this, but i have not idea how to go about this.
What could cause the `nan` values in the 3-layered model, and what steps do i have to take to make this work?

Comment: What is the data you train with? Is it scaled?

Comment: I got the data from here: ``https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stedy/Machine-Learning-with-R-datasets/master/insurance.csv`` It is a table containing age, bmi, number of children, gender, insurance charges, region and smoking/nonsmoking. I use the column for the charges as my ``y_train`` data, and the rest, after one-hot encoding some columns, as ``X_train``. I don't know if the data is scaled or not.

Comment: Looking at the table, the data is not scaled, as you have values like `16884.924` for  `charges` for example. Neural networks need data to be scaled, otherwise you can get exploding gradients. This could be the case here, the numbers could get so big through multiplication in the layers, they get `nan`.

Comment: I added a ``Normalization`` layer as the first layer and now i get no more ``nan`` values - thanks! Why don't you make your comment a "real" answer, then i can upvote it,

Answer (score 2):

The used data is unscaled and should be scaled with e.g. a [StandardScaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html). Unscaled data, multiplied with the weights of the layers, could lead to exploding numbers, which then are `nan`s. For categorical features (like the `sex`, `children`, or `region` features in your dataset) you can use a [one-hot encoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html).

Regarding your comment to the question, instead of using a `Normalization` layer as first layer, you could (and most likely should) use a scaler, e.g. a StandardScaler to scale your data. Don't forget to only fit it on the training data and then transform the training and test data. A `BatchNormalization` layer learns its normalization through its weights over batches and should only be an intermediate layer.